Is there a clear use case for partition by in ST_ClusterDBSCAN?
If I want to create clusters of point, what would be the use case for adding PARTITION BY some columb to ST_ClusterDBSCAN function?
I understand if I want clusters within states, e.g. In that case partitioning by state make sense, assuming no cross state clusters are needed.
But, if we need clusters across whole set of data, is there ever a use case for partitioning?

That is...an odd question to answer. No partitioning is just one use case among countless with partitioning. There is also declarative, inherent partitioning via PARTITION BY, and implicit aggregation partitioning via a query-level GROUP BY (these work on different result set assumptions, though). Anyways, imagine your data set has categories, say, those points are GPS tracks of outdoor activities, and you want individual clustering over people who hike and people who bike, you'd use something like PARTITION BY <activity_type>.
